# Is it possible to run threads at different time interval- JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have 8 threads in JMeter, which i am executing for every 5 minutes using Task scheduler.

Now i have included 2 threads which want to run for 5 times per day only (ex: at 12am, 5am,10am...)

when the moment comes, the execution shall be 8+2 & remaining time, it shall be only 8 threads.

Is it possible to configure such usecase in Jmeter..

Comment: you can run same jmeter file with parameterized thread group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use the same .jmx script and want to execute either 8 or 10 "threads" (whatever it is), you can go for:

1. [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) - for conditional execution of this or that test elements
2. [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) to check current time, an example condition which trigger the test at i.e. 5 AM would be:

   ```
   ${__groovy(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == 5 && Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE) == 0,)}
   ```